# What is a raw prefix argument? (capital P in interactive)

Tags: interactive, prefix-argument

And what can they be used for?

`(interactive "p")` takes a numerical argument from the `universal argument` right? And the universal argument is just an int either way, so what does capital `(interactive "P")` do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hard to believe that people described this here without also giving you links to Emacs's own descriptions of this:

- In the Emacs manual, node [Arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html).
- In the Elisp manual, node [Prefix Command Arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html).

***"Ask Emacs!":*** `C-h i`, choose a manual, `i prefix argument RET`.

In a nutshell, though this is said well enough by other answers here, and is described in detail in the manual:

- The **"raw"** prefix arg provides Lisp values of different kinds, and in particular it distinguishes *whether or not the user actually used* a prefix argument (of any kind).

  Using it, a program can distinguish whether the user used one of {`-`, `M--`, `C--`} or one of {`M-- 1`,  `C-- 1`, `C-u -1`} (both of which have the same numeric prefix value of `-1`), and distinguish whether s?he used `C-u C-u` or one of {`M-16`, `C-16`, `C-u 16`} (both of which have numeric value 16) - among lots of other distinctions.

  But the most important such distinction is `nil` vs non-`nil`: many commands act differently depending on whether the user uses a prefix arg.
- The **"numeric"** prefix arg is really just the value that function `prefix-numeric-value` returns when applied to the raw prefix arg.  IOW, it is best thought of as a mapping from the actual raw user interaction to an integer.

  It cannot tell you whether the user actually used a prefix argument, because the default of no prefix argument maps to the integer 1, just as does the use of `C-u 1`, `M-1`, or `C-1`.

Answer (score 10):

When raw prefix [*Interactive Code*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html) `"P"` is used, the argument is passed on as it is whereas `"p"` converts the arg to a number.

After evaluating the below elisp, try out `C-u M-x my/fn-with-num-arg` and then `C-u M-x my/fn-with-raw-arg` to see the difference because `C-u` passes a list argument `(4)`.

```el
(defun my/debug-fn (arg)
  (let ((msg))
    (if (numberp arg)
        (setq msg (format "Argument is number %s. " (pp arg)))
      (setq msg "Argument is not a number. "))
    (if (listp arg)
        (setq msg (concat msg (format "Arg is %s." (pp arg))))
      (setq msg (concat msg "Argument is not a list.")))
    (message msg)))

(defun my/fn-with-num-arg (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (my/debug-fn arg))
;; Result of C-u M-x my/fn-with-num-arg :
;; Argument is number 4. Argument is not a list.

(defun my/fn-with-raw-arg (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (my/debug-fn arg))
;; Result of C-u M-x my/fn-with-raw-arg :
;; Argument is not a number. Arg is (4)
;; .
```

Also the argument defaults to `1` for numerical argument (`"p"`) but defaults to `nil` or `()` for raw argument (`"P"`).

*My few cents: At times, the deciding factor for whether to use `"p"` or `"P"` is whether you want the default argument to be `1` or `nil`.*

```el
;; Result of M-x my/fn-with-num-arg :
;; Argument is number 1. Argument is not a list.

;; Result of M-x my/fn-with-raw-arg :
;; Argument is not a number. Arg is nil.
```

Comment: Thanks. I get that sometimes it is better to get `nil` than `1`, but never that having a wrapped `int` is preferable to an unwrapped `int`. (Can't upvote until I get 15 points, btw).

Comment: @24HrRevengeTherapist: just up-voted ya', taking you past the magic 15 point threshold.  Go out and do some up-voting on items that help you!

Comment: It's not about wrapped vs unwrapped ints. It's not about ints at all. And +1 to @kaushalmodi for emphasizing that you can tell whether the user used a prefix arg only by using the raw arg (by checking whether the value is `nil` or not).

Comment: What's the rationale for the C-u default argument being `(4)` and not, uhm, `(42)`, 42, or perhaps -23? I ask because the `(4)` is often dutifully mentioned but rarely explained. My working hypothesis is that Stallman happened to have four bits of toilet paper left when he came up with it.

Comment: My best guess is that `4` just hit the sweet spot for the use cases you might not be aware of: `C-u` is equal to `(4)`, `C-u C-u` gives `(16)` and `C-u C-u C-u` gives `(64)` and so on. This number might be empirically derived where the early emacs dev found 3^2 = 9 to be too small a number and 5^2 = 25 too large. E.g. `C-u C-u C-n` will move the cursor down by 16 lines, which could be roughly half the screen height in olden times.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add a bit more detail to @kaushalmodi's answer (and useful test case):

The raw argument lets you distinguish between arguments provided with `universal-argument` and `digit-argument`.

With a numeric prefix arg there is no way to distinguish the universal argument `C-u` from a prefix arg of 4 (i.e. `C-4`). With the raw argument these are different: `(4)` vs `4`.

The same applies with `negative-argument`. As a raw argument you can distinguish between `C--` and `C-- 1`: the first will give you `-` while the second `-1`. When converted to a numeric argument they will both be `-1`.

So the benefit of using a raw argument is it gives you more possible values. You can write commands that behave differently depending on how the argument is specified.

As an example, take a look at the doc string for `yank`. This command treats `C-u` and `C-4` differently:

> With just C-u as argument, put point at beginning, and mark at end.
>   With argument N, reinsert the Nth most recent kill.